# Aggregate list initialization with another aggregate object

Tags: c++, c++14, aggregate-initialization

I have:

```
struct DisplayConfig {
    int width;
    int height;
    int colorDepth;
};
```

And another aggregate:

```
struct DisplayResolution {
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

I'd like to us them like:

```
DisplayResolution resolution{1920, 1080};
DisplayConfig config{r, 32};
```

Which does not work.

Changing `DisplayConfig` to:

```
struct DisplayConfig {
    DisplayResolution resolution;
    int colorDepth;
};
```

will work, but changing `DisplayConfig` is not an option, also accessing  `config.width` won't work anymore.

`DisplayConfig{r.width, r.height, 32};` sure works, but is sintax similar to:

```
DisplayConfig config{r, 32};
```

possible?

Comment: No. Sorry. It is not possible.

Comment: If changing `DisplayConfig` was an option then you could have it inherit from `DisplayResolution` to keep `config.width` and allow the aggregate initialization...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible given your condition: "changing `DisplayConfig` is not an option". 
The class `DisplayConfig` does satisfy the conditions of an aggregate (in C++14) as it has with no user-provided constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions.

When initializing such an aggregate by an initializer list, the following applies:

> **8.5.1 Aggregates [[dcl.init.aggr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr)**
>   ...
>   [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr#2) When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, **the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate**, in increasing subscript or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause. If the initializer-clause is an expression
>   and a narrowing conversion is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed. [ Note: If an initializer-clause is itself an initializer list, the member is list-initialized, which will result in a recursive application of the rules in this section if the member is an aggregate. —end note ]

So in the following statement:

```
DisplayConfig config{r, 32};
```

`r` is taken as the initializer of the first member of `DisplayConfig` which is `width`. This results in an error because of conversion failure:

```
error: cannot convert 'DisplayResolution' to 'int' in initialization
     DisplayConfig config{ r, 32 };
                             ^
```

and a warning because the `depth` member of `DisplayConfig` class is not given given an initializer:

```
warning: missing initializer for member 'DisplayConfig::colorDepth' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```